# VBA search for different row values on the same column and copy/paste specific information in one row

Tags: excel, vba

I have this excel workbook that has hundreds of records, which in this case a person can have several records attached to their name. I would like to sort through these records and find specific information only and copy/paste them in one row.

I have this sample code that can only copy/paste values all the values in a column:

```
Sub match_columns()
Dim I, total, fRow As Integer
Dim found As Range

total = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 1 To total
    answer1 = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & I).Value
 Set found = Sheets(2).Columns("K:K").Find(what:=answer1) 'finds a match
If found Is Nothing Then   
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q" & I).Value = "NO MATCH"
Else
    fRow = Sheets(2).Columns("K:K").Find(what:=answer1).Row
    Worksheets(1).Range("O" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("O" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("P" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("P" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("Q" & fRow).Value
 End If
Next I

End Sub
```

I am attaching a sample of what the excel sheet looks like and how it should be[image: Picture] in one line. I appreciate all the help and pointers you could provide.

Many Thanks,

Charls.

Comment: First point; use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Also, you need to repeat the variable type: `Dim I as Long, total as Long, fRow As Long`.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing though?

Comment: BigBen - Thanks for the pointers, are you suggesting to repeat the variable type for each specific data that I am looking (Algebra, Biology, 7, 1, etc). The issue is that I am not able to sort for the specific values and display them in one row.

Comment: You should repeat the variable type for every variable yes, otherwise it is a `Variant`.